# Passing multiple parameters using karate.call

Tags: automation, cucumber, karate, web-api-testing

I am trying to call an API in second feature file , passing arguments from first feature file . Say token and current page value which is returned from a first API response.These has to be passed as a param for second API

```
   * def activeDetails =
    """
      function(times){
        for(i=0;i<=times;i++){
          karate.log('Run test round: '+(i+1));
          karate.call('getActiveRouteDetails.feature', { token: token, currentPage: i });
        }
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(1*1000);
      }
    """
* call activeDetails totalPages
```

In my second feature , I am able to print the values passed , but unable to pass in params . Can you please help me

```
And print currentPage
And print token
And param pageNumber  = '#currentPage'
And param token = token
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a subtle difference when you are in a JavaScript block. Please read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-expressions

Make this change:

```
var result = karate.call('examples/getDetails.feature', { token: token, currentPage, i });
```

And please don't have variable names like `current page`, take the help of a JavaScript programmer friend if needed for help.

Also note that the best practice is to avoid JS code and loops as far as possible: https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops

Comment: @PeterSmith Thank you Sir.I will update the code after going the links you provided. I am facing another issue as mentioned. Can you please provide your input